# hackerearth - List Rotation Question - runtime error NZEC

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I keep running into this NZEC error when I submit my code. I did my best to solve it, but I just dont know whats going wrong.

Here is the [question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/)
It is the one titled **"Monk and Rotation"** I would paste the direct link but the url doesnt change for the question index nor questions themselves

```
TestCases=int(input())
for i in range(TestCases):
  InputArray=[]
  RotatedArray=[]
  #Preprocessing start
  params=input()#obtaining parameters for list
  length=int(params[0])
  rotations=int(params[2])
  elements=input()
  j=0
  while j<=len(elements): #Convert and Loading the elements into actual list
    temp=int(elements[j])
    InputArray.append(temp)
    j=j+2
  #end of preprocessing
  #start of reducing number of rotations if they exceed list length
  while(rotations>=len(InputArray)):
    rotations=rotations-len(InputArray)
  #end  
  j=0
  for j in range(len(InputArray)):
    temp=InputArray[j-rotations]
    RotatedArray.append(temp)
  j=0
  print(*RotatedArray,sep=" ")
  #start of deleting the lists used
  del InputArray[:]
  del InputArray
  del RotatedArray[:]
  del RotatedArray
  #del elements[:]
  #del elements
  #end
```

Example input

```
1
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

Example Output

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

When I submit the code the testing computer randomly detects its first or second runs as correct while the other remaining ones return a NZEC error

I am not sure what is wrong, I know I am not getting a negative index call as I made sure the number of rotations does not exceed the length of array. And as for memory as you can see in the last 6 lines I added "del" statements to forcefully clear the lists.

Though for some reason when when I also clear the "elements" string I get NZEC error for all of the test computer's inputs so I'm not sure about that.

I have test the code with my own inputs copied and pasted from notepad for upto 10 test cases and all of them passed with no error.

What am I doing wrong and how exactly do these online tester even work with these inputs. And how can I avoid this sort of problems in the future

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to manually `del` lists. Memory is managed automatically. Also, try running this locally and see if you get an error that hackerearth might be hiding.

Comment: I cannot see the question but I'm guessing that the inputs are meant to be treated as lists. In other words, you may need to convert an input with extra spaceslike, say, "1 2        3 4 5" to an array like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Note that the code, as written, will fail if some of the numbers are greater than 9.